# Cluster analysis with LAMP

Tags: php, cluster-analysis, lamp, dendrogram

I am looking for a way to do some data cluster analysis. This is way out of my league but i know it can be done. I am looking for ways to cluster the data that i have and present it in a visual way. One that come to mind is a dendrogram but i am open to other suggestions as well.

Are there any scripts or classes that have been already written that would be able to help me with this task? I prefer to stay within LAMP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complete open source tool I know is the carrot2 open source framework for document clustering. They're primarily java and .NET centric but can be used with Ruby and PHP5 through the REST interface. Should be relatively easy to integrate into whatever framework you choose to work with.

This is their homepage - http://project.carrot2.org/index.html

This is their online demo of their cluster engine and visualization, the circle visualization may interest you (once you enter a query there's 3 visual output tabs, it's the middle one) - http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search

This is their commercial product, lingo3g - http://search.carrotsearch.com/carrot2-webapp/search . It's 6-8x faster at clustering most queries, gives different (better?) clustering of results, and provides hierarchical clustering and corresponding visualization. If you want to use that you can request a trial you can send them an e-mail, they'll give you access to all the corresponding materials (as the carrot2 open source download) with a 2 month trial license.

If this isn't what you're looking for and you want just a raw collection of libraries, you can also check out apache's mahout project.